# Image moves after CATransform3DMakeRotation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an UIImageView with an image. This image gets rotated arround the z Axis with this method:

```
- (void)rotate {
    if (self.currentDegrees >= self.desiredDegrees) {
        [self.timer invalidate];
    } else {
        self.currentDegrees += 1.0;
        self.myUIImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(self.currentDegree, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

There is a NSTimer which calls this method with a frequency of 0.1 seconds. After the image has rotated to the desired position, the Timer gets invalidated. I use the Timer to get a little animation.

Now the problem:
When I push another ViewController (Navigation Controller is used) and go back to my inital ViewCOntroller with the image, the image moves it's position or gets smaller. This happens about 30% of the time.

The same thing happens when I touch a TextField.

Comment: Are you using autolayout? It might try to lay out the view again but as the transform isn't identity, it might get it wrong.

Comment: Thank you this was exactly the problem.